# Subclassing generic class in Swift fails

Tags: swift, generics, swift3

I am fairly new to generic programming and am having an issue with Swift 3 and subclassing a generic class. I've stripped it all down to a simple case that fails and am hoping someone can help explain why I'm getting the failure.

With the following protocol and classes, everything works fine. This works (my real code has a lot more going on but works fine):

```
protocol P {
  associatedtype T
}

class Temp<X> {}
class C1<D:P> {
  init(tmp: Temp<D.T>) {}
}
```

However, when I subclass as follows:

```
class C2<L:P> : C1<L> {}
```

I get this compiler failure:

```
<unknown>:0: error: expression type 'Temp<_>' is ambiguous without more context
```

The error is not on a specific line, but rather a failure that appears in the compiler activity log.

Maybe there is something simple that I'm missing, but I just don't see it. My subclass has the same constraint as the base class (that is, it must adopt protocol P), so it seems to me that this should work.

Any thoughts?

Comment: It looks like the issue is somewhere else. The code contained in this question compiles without problem (using Swift 3.1). It's likely that you have a mismatch between the generic type `X` of an instance of `Temp` and the expected type `D.T` or you have not specified a generic type at the instantiation of `C1` or `C2` (`let foo = C2<ConcreteTypeImplementingP>(tmp: someValue)`.

Comment: @Palle don't know where you tried it, because on playground (Swift 3.1) it does not compile

Comment: I tried to fix your error, but everything seems fine to me. I only noticed that by commenting the init or by overriding it in the subclass, it starts to compile. Looks like the compiler is unable to figure out the `D.T` type

Comment: This looks like a bug – the code doesn't compile in Swift 3.0.2, but does in Swift 3.1.

Comment: @LucaD'Alberti I tried it in the REPL and using a file which I compiled using `swiftc`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I start by saying that I couldn't figure out why your problem is happening, but I hope this can help you somehow

Let's start from the `C1` class.

```
class C1<D: P> {}
```

By using this, everything works fine then. So I wanted to make sure that the generic parameter could be used inside `C1` and `C2` and actually it can

```
class C1<D: P> {
    // it compiles
    let something: D.T? = nil

    // it compiles
    func doSomething(using parameter: D.T) {
    }

    // do not compile
    init(_ some: D.T) {
    }
}
```

At the end, if you override the `init` in the `C2` class, the code finally compile.
I think it can actually be a compiler issue and I would try to file a radar for this. I don't know actually what else to try.

Comment: Thank you @Luca! Overriding the `init` does solve the issue, though I agree that there must be some bug in the compiler. My particular use case is a bit more complicated, and creating a new init with different names for the parameters solved the issue.